# Как устранить конфликты между скриптами на jQuery?

Tags: jquery, requirejs

Вопрос сложный, нужно НЕ готовое решение, прошу помочь объяснением в какую сторону копать и как можно устранить ошибки и возможно ли это вообще с конкретным исходником?

1. Платформа: Magento 2 (Движок интернет магазина).
2. Устанавливаю Slider Revolution Jquery версия.[image: Директория]
3. Все js в Magento 2 загружаются с помощью RequereJS. Создаю конфигурационный файл `requirejs-config.js` для объявления зависимостей скриптов от Slider Revolution Jquery с библиотекой jQuery.

```js
        var config = {
        map: {
            '*': {
      themepunchTools:          'js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min',
            themepunchRevolution:     'js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min',
      }
        },
        shim: {
      themepunchTools: {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            themepunchRevolution: {
                deps: ['jquery', 'themepunchTools']
            }
        }
    };
```

4. Сам по себе Slider Revolution Jquery содержит аж 12 файлов, 9 из которых загружаются как Ajax. И они не внесены в конфигурацию RequereJS, а подключены непосредственно в файле jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.[image: Список]
5. Ошибки в консоли:[image: Ошибки]
6. Вывод: насколько я понял сами исходники написаны плохо и имеют очень много глобальных функций. Возможно ли как-то решить данный вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

А не может быть проблемы в последовательности подключения скриптов? Что-то вызывается раньше и запрашивает то, что ещё не погрузилось. Проверьте эту теорию, перенастройте `require`.